# caffe cudnn version 4 & 5

Tags: c++, cuda, caffe, pow, cudnn

I use cudnn acceleration in my caffe program.
I use cudnn 4 at the begin and it's working fine but when I updated the cudnn to version 5.0, the pow function doesn't work. 
The calling function is in the batch_norm layer as

```
caffe_gpu_powx(variance_.count(), variance_.gpu_data(), Dtype(0.5), variance_.mutable_gpu_data());
```

And the data after calling doesn't change. 
The pow function is defined as below, as same as in the caffe github banch

```
template <typename Dtype>
\__global__ void powx_kernel(const int n, const Dtype* a,
    const Dtype alpha, Dtype* y)
 {
     CUDA_KERNEL_LOOP(index, n)
     {           
         y[index] = pow(a[index], alpha);  
     }  
}

template <>
void caffe_gpu_powx<float>(const int N, const float* a,
    const float alpha, float* y) {
    // NOLINT_NEXT_LINE(whitespace/operators)
    powx_kernel<float><<<CAFFE_GET_BLOCKS(N), CAFFE_CUDA_NUM_THREADS>>>(
      N, a, alpha, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake that I have set the code generation to "compute_52,sm_52" at the begin with TITAN X, but now a lower GPU should be set to "compute_20,sm_20". And it's working fine now.

Comment: That setting doesn't make sense. CUDNN requires a compute capability >=3.0 device to run. What device are you actually trying to run on?